# Strange commit hash in Git repo

Tags: git

I had a tag that I forced to a new commit, then I force pushed it upstream:

```
$ git tag -f 4.2.0/1900 releases/4.2.0
Updated tag '4.2.0/1900' (was bab88f3)

$ git push -f upstream 4.2.0/1900
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git@stash:7999/ab/repo.git
 + bab88f3...9523283 4.2.0/1900 -> 4.2.0/1900 (forced update)
```

I noticed that it was showing `bab88f3` as the previous commit the tag was referencing. So, I did a log:

```
$ git log bab88f3 -1
commit 0d17fc10d0fd17e2def7544a8db3e1558ba2453d
```

That's not the commit I expected to see. What is going on? Why does `bab88f3` not show up in my logs at all?

Comment: What does `git show bab88f3` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that `bab88f3` is the (abbreviated) ID of an annotated tag object, with said object pointing to commit `0d17fc10d0fd17e2def7544a8db3e1558ba2453d`.  When you ran:

```
git tag -f 4.2.0/1900 releases/4.2.0
```

you told git to erase the old lightweight tag `4.2.0/1900` (which pointed to the annotated tag object) and replace it with whatever `releases/4.2.0` identifies, apparently commit `9523283`.

Normally, the only things that point to annotated tag objects are other tags (either other annotated tags, or more typically, the lightweight tag created when creating an annotated tag).

Comment: So when I forced the tag, it is no longer annotated? That's disappointing and subtle. I guess the right way to fix a tag is to completely delete it then make a new one. Great answer, thank you.

Comment: Correction, I should have done: `git tag -a -f <tag> <new commit>`